# How to import an Excel file to Python? [New to Python]

Tags: python, excel, import

I'm currently using the following code (as learned in the DataCamp courses I followed):

```
import pandas as pd

pd.read_excel('C:\Users\jeenb\OneDrive\Bureaublad\Master Finance\Master Thesis\Input Python\Training Set.xlsx')
```

I'm getting the following error message:

```
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

I've tried the following as was suggested in this forum before:

```
pd.read_excel('C:\\Users\\jeenb\\OneDrive\\Bureaublad\\Master Finance\\Master Thesis\\Input Python\\Training Set.xlsx')

pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\jeenb\OneDrive\Bureaublad\Master Finance\Master Thesis\Input Python\Training Set.xlsx')

pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\jeenb\OneDrive\Bureaublad\Master Finance\Master Thesis\Input Python\Training Set.xlsx")
```

All of these give the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jeenb\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pandas\compat\_optional.py", line 126, in import_optional_dependency
    module = importlib.import_module(name)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1004, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openpyxl'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#17>", line 1, in <module>
    pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\jeenb\OneDrive\Bureaublad\Master Finance\Master Thesis\Input Python\Training Set.xlsx")
  File "C:\Users\jeenb\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 311, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\jeenb\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 457, in read_excel
    io = ExcelFile(io, storage_options=storage_options, engine=engine)
  File "C:\Users\jeenb\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 1419, in __init__
    self._reader = self._engines[engine](self._io, storage_options=storage_options)
  File "C:\Users\jeenb\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_openpyxl.py", line 524, in __init__
    import_optional_dependency("openpyxl")
  File "C:\Users\jeenb\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pandas\compat\_optional.py", line 129, in import_optional_dependency
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Missing optional dependency 'openpyxl'.  Use pip or conda to install openpyxl.
```

I'm typing this code in the IDLE Shell 3.10.2. Previously I got an error message while importing the pandas however since I don't get this anymore I feel like I fixed this.

Comment: Did you install `openpyxl` using pip or conda like the error suggests?

Comment: I used pip, using the pip install openpyxl command.

Comment: Are you using anaconda or pyenv/virutalenv ? (these create  multiple python environments and you might be using a different environment to run the code.  )  You can check all the packages istalled in current env by running `pip list`. Also, are you running the code from command prompt or a jupyter notebook (in a browser)

Comment: I'm not using anaconda, pyenv or virutalenv. I'm not running my code in either, I'm running it in a program called IDLE Shell 3.10.2.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you  need to open your command prompt, activate the environment you are using and type: pip install openpyxl

Comment: I've did this and when I tried to do this again got the following message: 

{C:\Users\jeenb>pip install openpyxl
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: openpyxl in c:\users\jeenb\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages (3.0.9)
Requirement already satisfied: et-xmlfile in c:\users\jeenb\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages (from openpyxl) (1.1.0)}

So  I think that's taken care of. However when writing and running the original code again, I still get the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. Thought I would post it if anyone in the future would be struggeling with this and found this post. My slashes were facing the wrong way, just changing \ to / fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case of using pycharm, I needed to go to File -> settings -> Project: projectName -> Python interpreter. Then click on + button will show you a pop up window to install packages. Then you can search for openpyxl and get the latest package. Then click Install package to install it.